# Finding minimum of binary tree recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to find the minimum value in a binary tree recursively(not a binary search tree). What's confusing me is the base case. What is returned if the TreeNode t is null? Since I am going to be using the returned value to compare it with the current minimum value (I think), I believe it is important what I return.

```
public static Object min(TreeNode t)
{  

  if(t == null)
     return ;
  else
     instantiate an object named mini
     compare it to min(t.getLeft())
        if mini is greater than it, mini equals t.getLeft()
     compare mini to t.getRight())
        if mini is greater, mini equals t.getRight
     return mini

}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about TreeNode in java, but if a object is null i would just return -1 or possibly 0.

Comment: As stated, +infinity is correct. But I'm not sure this is the right question you're asking, since probably the right way is not to recurse to null nodes. Perhaps you can show the rest of your code? (It's also a bit weird than the return type is Object).

Comment: that would not work because 0 could be greater that the current minimum

Answer (score 1):

You currently have `Object` as the return type of `min` but you probably want something more specific. For example, if tree contains integers, then the return type would be `Integer` or `Long`. As long as there is some reasonable maximum value for that type that `min` returns that's what you should return in the base case. So, for example, if your tree contains integers then return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Why? Because you're guaranteed that everything else will be less than that so the base case won't adversely affect the results.

Comment: is there a String.MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: @Andrew What would the max value for a String be? How would that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If this was C or C++ you could just use pointer. Java does not have it. But, you can simulate something like that.
Or you can define a Object that contains a data and boolean.

```
class A { 
    int a; // or whatever you want
    bool is_null = false; // default value
} A_NULL = {0, true};
```

If you found a data, then put the data in the object and return it.
If you didn't just return A_NULL.